# Build proto3 gRPC API with overloaded endpoints

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am fairly new to API building, so this may be a broader question than I originally posed.
I am creating an API in Golang (using protobuf 3 and gRPC) that has two similar endpoints:

- GET /project/genres
- GET /project/{id}

The problem is that when I run `curl localhost:8080/project/genres`, the pattern matching results in the `/project/{id}` endpoint getting called with `genres` as the id. Is there some simple way around this, or do I have to build something into the server code to call the proper function based on the type?

I also tried flipping the ordering of these definitions, just in case the pattern matching had some order of operations that I didn't know about, but this didn't make a difference.

Here are the definitions in my proto file:

```
message EmptyRequest { }
message ProjectRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message GenreResponse {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}

message ProjectResponse {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
}

service ProjectService {
  rpc GetProject(ProjectRequest) returns (ProjectResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/project/{id}"
    };
  }
  rpc GetGenres(EmptyRequest) returns (GenreResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/project/genres"
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to specify a check in the url path template to get around this issue:

```
 rpc GetGenres(EmptyRequest) returns (GenreResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
    get: "/v1/project/{id=genres}"
  };
}
```

This seems to have fixed the problem. I don't know if there are other solutions, or if this is the right way to do this, but I'm happy to accept other answers if something better comes in.